# Flutter Firestore Cached Netwok Image Time

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, caching

I have a social media app and I get photos from firebase and show them on my home screen. In this process, I use `Cached Network Image` to load photos faster and the photos are successfully cached. What I'm wondering is whether these cached photos automatically clean themselves after a certain time, if they do, after how much time has passed. If it doesn't clean, what should I do for it to automatically clean itself?

Comment: The defaults are 30 days and 200 items. Source - https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/616#issuecomment-862177443.

Comment: I was wondering the default time thank you.